# How to measure the independence of random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I need a function, which measures, how independent are two random variables.

Ideally,

- It should give 0, if the variables are completely independent ($\rm{P(AB)=P(A)P(B)}$).
- It should give 1, if the variables are completely dependent ($\rm{A=B}$).

Obviously also a reverse result is okay.

After digging the net and my old remembers, I found something like $\rm\frac{P(AB)}{P(A)P(B)}$. This is trivially correct for complete independency. But it gives $\rm\frac{1}{P(A)}$ if $\rm{A=B}$, what is not what I want.

Comment: What about the correlation between $\mathbf{1}_A$ and $\mathbf{1}_B$?

Comment: @StefanHansen I don't know this markup, what is $1_\rm A$?

Comment: It's the indicator function for the event $A$.

Comment: @StefanHansen Oops, I possibly formulated the question badly. Maybe I should have used random *events*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correlation coëfficient of random variables $\mathbf1_A$ and $\mathbf1_B$ is what comes to mind:
$$\rho\left(\mathbf{1}_{A},\mathbf{1}_{B}\right)=\frac{\mathsf{Cov}\left(\mathbf{1}_{A},\mathbf{1}_{B}\right)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}\left(\mathbf{1}_{A}\right)}\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}\left(\mathbf{1}_{B}\right)}}=\frac{P\left(A\cap B\right)-P\left(A\right)P\left(B\right)}{\sqrt{P\left(A\right)\left(1-P\left(A\right)\right)P\left(B\right)\left(1-P\left(B\right)\right)}}$$
Here $\mathbf1_A$ is a random variable that takes value $1$ if $\omega\in A$ (i.e. if event $A$ occurs) and takes value $0$ otherwise.

Comment: It is worth noting that two random variables can be uncorrelated and still not be independent.

Comment: But this can be negative. In the case when A and B do not intersect, for example. In fact it can take any negative real value - If we take P(A)=1-ε=P(B) for some ε<1/2 and suppose P(AnB)=1-2ε then this measure gives -ε/(1-ε), which explodes negatively near 0.
So I think this a pretty bad measure of dependence of two events.

Comment: @toe-pose Yes it can take negative values. Just like degrees that are used as unit to measure temperature. I do not see though why this makes it a pretty bad measure. Do you want to close your eyes for the distinction between positive and negative dependency? I don't, but if you do then just take its absolute value.

Answer (score 3):

The correlation coefficient between two random variables $X$ and $Y$ is a measure of linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$. For example, $Y$ can be a nonlinear function of $X$ and still $\operatorname{Corr}(X,Y)=0$. A better way of measuring the dependence between $X$ and $Y$ would be [normalized mutual information](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7914/8020ef42aff36f0649bccc94c9711f9b884f.pdf):
$$
I^*(X,Y)=\frac{I(X,Y)}{\sqrt{H(X)H(Y)}} \in [0,1],
$$
where $I(X,Y)=D_{KL}(P_{X,Y}||P_X\otimes P_Y)$ is the mutual information between $X$ and $Y$, and $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$ are the corresponding entropies. When $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $I(X,Y)=0$ and, therefore, $I^*(X,Y)=0$. When $X=Y$, $I^*(X,Y)=1$ as required.

Comment: Hi! Good comment! There are also other measures as far as I know now, for instance, distance correlation.