# How to measure the (in)dependence of multiple random variables?

Tags: probability, independence

To measure the (in)dependence between two random variables, we can use correlation coefficients. See, e.g., [How to measure the independence of random variables?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3553704/how-to-measure-the-independence-of-random-variables).

What about multiple random variables? Do we have a generalized measure for that?

Comment: yes, its the mutual information

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, but AFAIK, mutual information also only considers two random variables. Are there different versions you are mentioning?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information Let $(X,Y) \in \mathcal X \times \mathcal Y$ In particular, take $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal Y$ to be whatever you'd like